# Resource recommendation for spintronics

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, electronics

What are some good beginner level books to understand [spintronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spintronics). I am looking for some sources in which basic mathematics of spintronics is properly explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with books on solid state physics, obviously. Beginner level material is "Kittel" or "Ashcroft/Mermin". You may continue with mathematically more involved books as, for instance, [Bruus/Flensberg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198566336) to understand the modern solid state physics notation. There some basic spintronics phenomena are already mentioned (Kondo effect and Luttinger Liquid). At some point you should be able to understand the following:

- I. Zutic, J. Fabian, S. D. Sarma, "Spintronics: Fundamentals and applications", [arXiv:cond-mat/0405528](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0405528), [*Rev. Mod. Phys.* **76**, 323-410 (2004)](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.76.323).